# Postgres tablespace size and reduction

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying postgres with a program that fetches data and puts it into the DB.

Right now the tablespace has filled the available space.
How can I cleanup the db in order to reduce it.
If I delete records, will the disk space be released?
Since I'd want to keep this under control, how can I say to postgres tablespace not to autoextend but to have a specific maximum sze?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible in Postgres to limit the size of a database, tablespace or table.

Comment: Put the data directory in a filesystem of limited size.

Comment: Ok and if I delete records, will disk space be released?